# Unity FB plugin update throwing SetUserSuffixAgent exception on Android. Not able to login

Tags: android, facebook, unity-game-engine

We recently upgraded our FB unity plugin from 7.9.4 to 7.13 in our unity game project. This works fine on all the platform excepts android. We are getting an exception mentioned below while trying to call FB.Init() function. We are not getting any call back from this function as well.

```
AndroidJavaException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no static method with name='SetUserAgentSuffix' signature='(Ljava/lang/String;)V' in class Ljava.lang.Object;
E/Unity   (18114): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no static method with name='SetUserAgentSuffix' signature='(Ljava/lang/String;)V' in class Ljava.lang.Object;
E/Unity   (18114):      at com.unity3d.player.ReflectionHelper.getMethodID(Unknown Source)
E/Unity   (18114):      at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.nativeRender(Native Method)
E/Unity   (18114):      at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.c(Unknown Source)
E/Unity   (18114):      at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$e$2.queueIdle(Unknown Source)
E/Unity   (18114):      at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:221)
E/Unity   (18114):      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
E/Unity   (18114):      at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$e.run(Unknown Source)
E/Unity   (18114):   at UnityEngine.AndroidJNISafe.CheckException () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
E/Unity   (18114):   at UnityEngine.AndroidJNISafe.CallStaticObjectMethod (IntPtr clazz, IntPtr methodID, UnityEngine.jvalue[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
E/Unity   (18114):   at UnityEngine.AndroidReflection.GetMethodMember (IntPtr jclass, System.String me
```

Our minSdkVersion = 19, targetSdkVersion = 27
Most of android libraries used in our project are of 27.1.1 version. for ex :- com.android.support.support-v4-27.1.1

Thanks,
Gaurav

Comment: I got this too, followed